# Easy way to set default values for variables in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of environment variables passed from client code, if they are not set, I need to set default values to them.

Except testing them one by one with a lot of `if ...; then ... fi`, is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have two files:

- a file containing the default value of variables.
- the client file

Source the default file and then the one from the client. This way, customer's values will be overwritten.

#### Test

Let's have these two files:

```
$ cat default 
export var1="foo"
export var2="bar"
export var3="bee"

$ cat customer 
export var2="yeah!"
```

Now, let's source them:

```
$ source default 
$ env | grep "^var"
var1=foo
var3=bee
var2=bar
```

Then let's get `customer`'s file:

```
$ source customer
$ env | grep "^var"
var1=foo
var3=bee
var2=yeah!
```

As you see, variable `$var2` has not the value from `customer`'s file, whereas the others have the value sest in `default`.

Comment: Wow! Much cleaner and easier to maintain than the parameter expansion way, thanks.

Comment: @LotusH nice that it was useful for you : )

Answer (score 5):

You can use [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like this:

```
foo=${foo:-default value}
```

This will set `$foo` to `"default value"` if it is not defined or empty(!).
Note that using the above code, you can't distinguish between a variable which has not being defined and a variable which has been explicitly set to an empty string. If that's fine for you, use it.

Comment: Why are you answering a duplicate.

Comment: I usually attach not too much attention on a question being duplicate or not. Probably I should have done it in this case. Now it's too late :) ...